# How to make a long horizontal scrollable navbar with dropdown in the same line with navbar-brand - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar d-flex flex-nowrap navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">


<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#premessa">Premessa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#data-puntuale">Dato Puntuale</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#trend">Trend</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#data-puntuale-vs-peers">Dato Puntuale vs. Peers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mappatura Del Rischio<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Separated link</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#trattamento">Trattamento Del Rischio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#survey-risk">Risk Top 10</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#governace">Governance</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#indicatori-statistici">Indicatori Economico/Finanziari</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#dscr">DSCR ed Indicatori Della Crisi</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#articolo-15">Misure Premiali</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#altri-indicatori">Altri Indicatori</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#nota-metodologica">Nota Metodologica</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried to make it scrollable horizontally with a dropdown menu-item, the problem is that when I add:

```
.navbar{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
display: inline-block;}
```

the drop down doesn't appear anymore. I cant figure it out how to have scrollability and dropdown together?

Also to have all navbar items in the same line I added `d-flex flex-nowrap` to navbar but in toggle mode it cause me another problem that the toggle button appear near to navbar-brand when I open the toggle button.

I can manage to get every single of them alone, but would like to have all these features together.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the following **css** on a basic navbar example seems to get what you're looking for... **working snippet** below:

**UPDATE**: update in light of the comment below by the questioner

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#premessa">Premessa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#data-puntuale">Dato Puntuale</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#trend">Trend</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#data-puntuale-vs-peers">Dato Puntuale vs. Peers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Mappatura Del Rischio<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Separated link</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#mappatura-rischio">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#trattamento">Trattamento Del Rischio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#survey-risk">Risk Top 10</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#governace">Governance</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#indicatori-statistici">Indicatori Economico/Finanziari</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#dscr">DSCR ed Indicatori Della Crisi</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#articolo-15">Misure Premiali</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#altri-indicatori">Altri Indicatori</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#nota-metodologica">Nota Metodologica</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  This is the rest of the page
  <section>
```

Comment: I'm not professional in Web but this seems to have all the page scrolling. Instead what I mean is scrolling navbar

Comment: This is not working either. But I'd accept a different answer in sense of shape of menu. I mean what is best in your opinion to implement a menu like this?

Comment: Not sure about your requirement?... but responsive design is all about avoiding having to scroll horizontally... if you have lots of links in you navigation, you’d have to go with burger menu on large screen sizes also;

Comment: Thank you for the help, I finally come up with the idea to group some menu items together in order not to overflow screen size horizontally and made a dropdown out of it.